# Interactive rebase shows me more commits than I'm asking for

Tags: git

I want to do an interactive rebase so I:
`git rebase -i HEAD~5`, but I'm getting more than `five` commits. Why could it be?

Comment: are there merges after `HEAD~5`?

Comment: Yes, one of these five is merge

Comment: then that's why. the rebase will ask you to include all commits not already included in `HEAD~5`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes a merge counts as only 1 commit, but it will show all the commits from the branch in the merge. So if you had 1 commit, 1 merge, 1 commit and you rebase -i HEAD~3 you might get all the commits in the merge along with the two end commits (which is more than three).