# Why are more than 1 commit squashed?

Tags: git

I have a branch that contains a top commit that was squashed so consisted of more than 1 commit before. Now i am trying to squash 2 top commits again with that commit :

> git reset —soft HEAD~1

Only now it has squashed way more than 2 commits? How to squash 2 commits properly  in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interactive rebase shows me more commits than I'm asking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767962/interactive-rebase-shows-me-more-commits-than-im-asking-for)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rebase+more+commits

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git rebase -i HEAD~1` to see exactly what's being squashed.